# summarize unique value, except select only one of multipication

Tags: hive, hql

I have a sample table as below

```
StoreID   RepID       OrderAmt
1234      CameronB      100,000
9075      HelenW      1,750,000
1234      JackM         700,000
7000      JasonA        325,000
705       JohnV         325,000
9075      MikeC         250,000
2111      PeterL        500,000
705       RickJ         660,000
501       ShareB        410,000
```

I would like to summarize OrderAmt by StoreID, however, need to pick only one RepID associated with the same store

Expected output

```
StoreID    RepID       Total_OrderAmt
1234       JackM           800,000
9075       MikeC         2,000,000
7000      JasonA           325,000
705       JohnV            985,000
2111      PeterL           500,000
501       ShareB           410,000
```

I am not sure if the following makes sense, if not, is there a proper way to achive the desired result?

```
Select StoreID, max(RepID) as RepID, sum(OrderAmt) as Total_OrderAmt
From HAVE
Group by StoreID, RepID
```

Comment: Just remove the RepID from GROUP BY statement and you should be good to go.

Comment: This works.  Greatly appreciated!